# Stacking functional models with python functions induce graph disconnection in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I want to connect the `model_1`:

```
x_a = Input((5,))
hidden_a = Dense(2)(x_a)
hidden_b = Dense(2)(x_a)
model_1 = Model(x_a, [hidden_a, hidden_b])
```

and `model_2`:

```
x_b = Input((2,))
output = Dense(1)(x_b)
model_2 = Model(x_b, output)
```

I can do it with the following line:

```
model_3 = Model(x_a, model_2(model_1.outputs[0]))
```

However I would like to define an arbitrarily number of models, and so I would like to use functions to do that.

Interestingly enough, when I try to embed each model in a function, as follows:

```
def model1():
  x_a = Input((5,))
  hidden_a = Dense(2)(x_a)
  hidden_b = Dense(2)(x_a)
  model_1 = Model(x_a, [hidden_a, hidden_b])
  return model_1

def model2():    
  x_b = Input((2,))
  output = Dense(1)(x_b)
  model_2 = Model(x_b, output)
  return model_2

input_a = Input((5,))
m1 = model1()
m2 = model2()
m3 = Model(input_a, m2(m1.outputs[0]))
```

I get an error:

`ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_3:0", shape=(?, 5), dtype=float32) at layer "input_3". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []`.

Basically I want to do the same as in this post: [Why when using this simple model with multiple outputs does Keras complain about a lack of gradients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215838/why-when-using-this-simple-model-with-multiple-outputs-does-keras-complain-about)

But with functions.

Is there a way to use function to do what I want, or do you think using custom layers would instead be better ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you design your model functions with the inputs, "model_inputs" and "sub_model_inputs", you can make this work. The fully working code (without gradient errors), can be seen below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

def model1(model_inputs, sub_model_inputs):
  #x_a = Input((5,))
  hidden_a = Dense(2)(sub_model_inputs)
  hidden_b = Dense(2)(sub_model_inputs)
  model_1 = Model(model_inputs, [hidden_a, hidden_b])
  return model_1

def model2(model_inputs, sub_model_inputs):    
  #x_b = Input((2,))
  output = Dense(1)(sub_model_inputs)
  model_2 = Model(model_inputs, output)
  return model_2

input_a = Input((5,))
m1 = model1(input_a, input_a)
m2 = model2(input_a, m1.outputs[0])
m3 = Model(input_a, m2.outputs)

m3.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

x= np.ones((10,5))
y = np.ones((10,1))
m3.train_on_batch(x,y)
```

the model_inputs is the input of the full model (combined of smaller models), while the sub_model_inputs correspond to the input of the particular sub model (example model1 and model2 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I think changing m3 to this should work:

```
m3 = Model(input_a, m2(m1(input_a)[0]))
```

The problem of your method is that there is no connection in your model-graph between input_a and the output of m2, so the model does not know what to do with input_a

Comment: The problem with this as mention in the link, is that we cannot use automatic differentiation afterwards, i.e `m3.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')`
`m3.train_on_batch(x,y)` will yield a None gradient somewhere.